# Xamarin Switchcell binding IsEnabledPropery not working?

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I'm just creating a simple example where I want to enable/disable a Switchcell (named switch2) by turning on/off another switchcell (named switch1).
I'm using the binding method. I've tried this code with an "Entry" element (trying to disable it) and it works perfectly, but with the property "IsEnabledProperty" of "switchcell" it seems not working. (I'm not using Xaml, i'm using PCL).
Xamarin Forms updated to the latest version (2.3.0.49).
Is this a Xamarin issue?
Here's the code:

```
 BindingContext = new DetailsViewModel();

        SwitchCell switch1 = new SwitchCell()
        {
            Text = "Switch",
        };
        switch1.SetBinding(SwitchCell.OnProperty, new Binding("Test", BindingMode.TwoWay));

        SwitchCell switch2 = new SwitchCell()
        {
            Text = "Visibilita",
        };
        switch2.SetBinding(SwitchCell.IsEnabledProperty, "Test");
```

and here is the DetailsViewModel.cs:

```
 public class DetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    bool test;


    public bool Test 
    { 
        get { return test; }
        set
        {
            if (test != value)
            {
                test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Test");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is bug from Xamarin, I think is not yet fixed first check without binding whether is working or not

Comment: Thank you, i've tried without binding and it's not working. Is there a workaround?